# How to add pdf file into your android project?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I have version 4.0.1 of Android studio. I'd like to use my program to fill out a set of predetermined pdf forms, but I can't figure out how to add them to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it at using [ResourceManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources) `res/raw/sample.pdf`. Your app will also need to set the minimum API level to 21 (Android 5.0).

```java
void readPDF(@RawRes int pdfResource) {
    InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(pdfResource);
}
```

Check this [article](https://www.pdftron.com/blog/android/build-an-android-pdf-viewer-using-java/) and update your question if you have trouble after you tried it.

Comment: Thank for the help! Managed to add the pdf to my project and set my API level above 21 but the name of the file is still red and marked with a questionmark.

Comment: What do you mean by marked with questionmark? Is it IDE issue? If yes, and you use Android Studio, try to invalidate cache and restart

Comment: The small icon next to the file has a questionmark in the corner ( i guess its not recognised), I also tried a clean build.

Comment: can you provide picture?

Comment: It's just a make up thing actually. It is actually recognizing. If you put any files in raw, its icon will be like question mark, but Android Studio can read it and do anything. But if you are obsessed about it (please don't be too hard on yourself), you can put it in `asset` like this tutorial https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/ (**beware, I haven't been tested it since API 19**)

Comment: If this question is solved, please mark it as solved so other can relate to it. Thanks.

Comment: Well the questionmark is not a big problem the fact that its still marked with red bothers me.

Comment: Just realised it was red because I did not add it to git, thanks a lot for the help!